# How to implement different instances of CKEDITOR with different config files on the same page?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have multiple instances of CKEDITOR on the same Angular page. For some instances I want to use config1.js for other type of CKEDITOR I want to use config2.js file.

The problem is if I open CKEDITOR with config1.js and then CKEDITOR with config2.js, my CKEDITOR initialise config2.js but then it also use config1.js (I can see consol.log() from config1.js been executed).

My question how to implement different config files for different CKEDITOR instances?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [customConfig](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-customConfig) property:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    customConfig: '/config1.js'
});
```

Comment: I am using customConfig. Maybe I try to explain my problem a bit clearer. I have 2 different config files: `config1` and `config2`. When I load CKEDITOR with `config1` everything works fine. But if I load CKEDITOR with `config2`, just after I initialised CKEDITOR with `config1` a `config2` is loaded as it should be, but just right after that my CKEDITOR also run `config1` because `config1` is already initialised. So what I want to do is to prevent CKEDITOR from using `config1` file when I initialise  CKEDITOR with `config2`.